# Отрендерить список с двумя переменными на основе HashMap при помощи Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Использую в своем сервисе движок для шаблонов  `thymeleaf` и хочу при помощи него отрендерить такое сообщение для емейла:

```
{
    "template": "sendErrors",
    "data": {
        "invoice uid 1": "error 1",
        "invoice uid 2": "error 2",
        "invoice uid 3": "error 3"
    }
}
```

Из JSON в поле data надо составить список такого вида:

> Произошла ошибка в инвойсе "uid". Причина ошибки: "error n".

В джава-классе, на который мапится json, поле data это `HashMap`. Как можно сконвертировать HashMap в html-список при помощи thymeleaf? В шаблоне должно быть две переменных для каждого элемента списка: номер инвойса и причина ошибки.

До этого я не работал с шаблонизаторами и нагуглил такой пример для thymeleaf:

```
<ul th:each="person : ${persons}">
    <li th:text="${person.name}"></li>
</ul>
```

Как его адоптировать для моей задачи?

Пример дата-класса:

```
public class Notification implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty
    private String template;

    @JsonProperty
    private HashMap data;

    public String getTemplate() {
        return template;
    }

    public void setTemplate(String template) {
        this.template = template;
    }

    public HashMap getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(HashMap data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Notification{" +
                "template='" + template + '\'' +
                ", data=" + data +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966653/print-key-value-in-thymeleaf-from-hashmap-arraylist. Там показано как перебрать мапу на клиенте